# Rails - in controller, how to render an action from a different controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a page where is displayed information about a respective car (it's a controller `cars`, action `show`). On this page, I render `_form` from the controller called `reviews`.

When I send out the form (through AJAX), the review is successfully created, but I am not able from the `reviews` controller render any action from the `cars` controller - to be more specific, here's the code:

```
# reviews_controller
  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.save
    #respond_with(@review)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :action => "/cars/car_profile" }
    end
  end
```

The error I get:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template reviews/cars/car_profile, application/cars/car_profile with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/adam/rubydev/claisy/app/views"
  * "/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in create'
  app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb:27:in `create'
```

How can I render in controller an action that is located in a different controller?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try to render `:template` instead of `:action`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:action` forces rails to search for templates within the current controller view folder.

> Missing template reviews/cars/car_profile

You should write this instead

```
render "cars/car_profile"
```

See [point 2.2.3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)

> What if you want to render a template from an entirely different
>   controller from the one that contains the action code? You can also do
>   that with render, which accepts the full path (relative to app/views)
>   of the template to render.